# Issue with moving a table from AWS RDS to AWS EMR using Sqoop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sqoop, amazon-emr

I have an AWS RDS database with a single table using postgres.
Now I want to move my data to AWS EMR so I can use Hadoop to process it.

I found this blog:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrate-rdbms-or-on-premise-data-to-emr-hive-s3-and-amazon-redshift-using-emr-sqoop/

And decided to give sqoop a shot, so I followed the method described in the blog.
However, when I try running this snippet to test the connection to RDS:

> sqoop eval --connect "jdbc:postgresql://****.****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432" --query "select count(*) from table ****" --username **** -P

I get the following error output:[error_part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBVEs.png)
[error_part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGcv8.png)

I tried looking up error code 600000 and parts of the error output to see if our people have had and resolved this issue before but with no luck.

Seems to me sqoop is having issue connecting to RDS, but for testing purposes, I've already set my RDS security rules to allow any in/outbound traffic.

I'm having issue figuring out what's causing this error and how to resolve it, but have no progress so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please paste the error messages rather than posting screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a SSL (transport layer encryption) problem.  Try updating your URL to:

```
"jdbc:postgresql://****.****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432?ssl=true"
```

That may make it use SSL and work appropriately.

Reference: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but still got the same errors.